# C# Excel changing cell type

Tags: c#, excel, ssis

I have built a solution (see my other question) that runs a SQL query, orders by invoice and creates an excel spreadsheet for each invoice. The problem I have is that I am using this as a connection:

```
                Excel_OLE_Con.ConnectionString = connstring;
                Excel_OLE_Con.Open();
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.Connection = Excel_OLE_Con;
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.CommandText = "Create table " + SheetName + " (" + TableColumns + ")";
                Excel_OLE_Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I have not found a way to use the Excel_OLE_con to do what I want so instead I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` instead.

I've tried having:

```
Excel_OLE_Cmd.Close();
```

at the end and then having this:

```
 Excel.Application x1Appl = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook x1WorkBook = x1Appl.Workbooks.Open(FolderPath + ExcelFileName + ".XLSX");

                Excel._Worksheet x1WorkSheet = x1WorkBook.Sheets[1];
                x1WorkSheet.Range["F2", "F2000"].NumberFormat = "#,###.00 €";
                x1Appl.Save();
```

then open the connection again and let the loop that writes into it happen as I've read I should format it before inputting the data into excel. This didn't work.

I've tried putting it at the end of the loop after closing connection (as the Excel application opens a new "connection".

But I am now getting this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.Save(Object Filename) 
>   at ST_6704c764a25b4ffa92f62385be46f235.ScriptMain.Main()

Any ideas on how to get around it?

Any different ways of setting the format? I thought this would help as I also needed to add formulas to certain cells in that sheet.

Comment: What's the value of: `FolderPath + ExcelFileName + ".XLSX"`

Comment: @Chris Folder Path (L:\MACROS\SSIS\output\LandedCost) and ExcelFileName is a variable taken from the query itself, it is the invoice number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your number format isn't working but here is something that has been working for me:

```
Range UnitCostCells = workSheet.get_Range("G1", "G1");
UnitCostCells.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "#,##0.0000";
```